# updating mysql field with variable not working

Tags: php, mysql, string, feed, concatenation

So I am using CONCAT to combine 2 strings together and want to update a TEXT field in my database by adding a new string onto the end of the existing string.

```
// This code works great. will add "EXTRA" at end of the feed.
$insert = ("update $username set feed = CONCAT(feed, 'EXTRA')");
mysql_query($insert);

// This code doesn't work. not sure what to change in the variable area?
$extra = "EXTRA";
$insert = ("update $username set feed = CONCAT(feed, '$extra')");
mysql_query($insert);
```

I tried many variations of the variable declaration but can't seem to get it to work like i can when i just write in a string. any help or insight is appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. /php.net/

Comment: Can you check what is the final query prepared by printing `$insert` ? I think `$extra` not replaced

Comment: yes. for the first code it will print "FEED EXTRA" and then "FEED EXTRA EXTRA" then "FEED EXTRA EXTRA EXTRA" and so on.
for the second example the feed remains the same and doesn't update or change, so will keep printing the same value. "FEED" "FEED" "FEED"

Comment: Try this: `$insert = ("update $username set feed = CONCAT(feed, \"$extra\")");` or `$insert = ("update $username set feed = CONCAT(feed, \'$extra\')");` or `$insert = ("update $username set feed = CONCAT(feed, '".$extra.'")");` or `$insert = ("update $username set feed = CONCAT(feed, $extra)");`

Comment: I just tried all 3 examples, i have tried one previously and unfortunately i'm still getting the same results for all of them... none. If i simply remove the $ so it becomes a string "extra", it adds it to the end of the feed perfectly. it really doesn't like that variable for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up your SQL here:

```
"update $username set feed = CONCAT(feed, 'EXTRA')"
```

`$username` = **TABLE NAME** ??

And looks like you probably want to update a field WHERE it equals a certain `$username` which would be:

```
"update TABLENAME set feed = CONCAT(feed, '$extra') WHERE username = '$username'"
```

Comment: my table is just one long row, so i don't need WHERE username = $username. I simply am using $username as the table name. And this code works great without the variable, that seems to be what needs to be fixed somehow. thanks.

Comment: so did this solve your question? if so mark as answer. Consider using clear variable names, not `$username` for table names, it is just very bad form.

Comment: this did not solve the question. the field cannot be updated with a variable, just a direct string, and still not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Look example query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field1 = CONCAT(field1, "new data" ) WHERE field2 = value;
```

and adjust to your needs.

Comment: yes, that will work fine, but if i replace "new data" with a variable like "$add" it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

To get the word 'EXTRA' at the end of feed I think you need to do something like this:

```
$insert = ("update $username set feed = CONCAT(feed, '" . $extra . "')");
```

Comment: I have tried this in the past and just again now with this exact syntax and i still don't have the feed updating with the variable text.